# Android Studio: Operation not permitted (Bind failed)

Tags: android, android-studio

was working on project, then tried to create new tabbed activity, and then in Build: Sync > I see an error: Operation not permitted (Bind failed), tried to reinstall, change Gradle file no luck, Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I updated to the latest version of Android studio, in my case (Android studio 4.2) It downloaded SDK files and Gradle files that seem to be missing. now everything is working fine. Hope this helps.